# How to write SUM function in Scheme?

Tags: scheme, sum, mit-scheme

How to write a function in scheme that sums the numbers in embedded lists?

i.e.  ((1) (2 3) (4) (5 6))

I wrote this to sum the regular list:

```
(define (sum list)
  (if (null? list)
      0
      (+ (car list) (sum (cdr list)))))
```

but I'm not sure how to do the embedded one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 3 cases:

```
(define (my-sum lst)
  (cond
    ; 1. the list is empty, so finish of by adding 0
    ([empty? lst]        0)
    ; 2. the first element is a list, so recurse down on the sublist, then do the rest
    ([list? (car lst)]   (+ (my-sum (car lst)) (my-sum (cdr lst))))
    ; 3. add the first element to the sum, then do the rest
    (else                (+ (car lst)          (my-sum (cdr lst))))))
```

so you were just missing the middle case.

This will work regardless of the nesting depth:

```
(my-sum '((1) (2 3) (4) (5 6)))
=> 21

(my-sum '((1) (2 3) (4) (5 6 (7 8 (9)))))
=> 45
```

Please note that you should not use the names "sum" and "list" in order not to shadow the build-in procedures.

Comment: Nothing wrong with shadowing builtins that are not used in a procedure as it won't leak the binding outside the definition.

Comment: @Sylwester It will work but I believe it's bad practice nevertheless - it'll bite you sooner or later.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest answer.

```
(define (sum list-of-lists)
  (apply + (apply append list-of-lists)))
```

and the 'proof':

```
> (sum '((1) (2 3) (4) (5 6)))
21
```

Answer (score -1):

In a more functional way

```
; this sums the elements of a not-embedded list
(define (sum-list* l)
  (foldl + 0 l))

; this sums the elements of an embedded list
(define (sum-embedded-list* el)
  (foldl + 0 (map sum-list* el)))
```

It covers the case of a list so formed: ((a1...an) (b1...bn)...), where ai and bj are atoms.
Foldl and map are two important functions in scheme (and other languages). If you don't know how to use them you should learn. Take a look [here](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html)

Comment: or simply "(foldl + 0 (map sum-list* el))"

Comment: but this works only one level down - try with '((1) (2 3) (4) (5 6 (7 8 (9)))) as in my answer

Comment: Yes, it works only one level down. Your code covers a nested list case. I don't know if Layla wants one or more level down (he wrote "embedded" lists and that example), but I was only pointing out the possibility of using some important list functions that can make the code more concise. However thanks for your clarification.

Comment: Yes if you want to use foldl, then it's best to right foldl* that will  do the car-cdr recursion where the car is a list.